# Почему слово "уважаемый" не всегда говорит об уважении?

Tags: лексика

Из словаря: УВАЖАЕМЫЙ,  Достойный уважения (**употребляется как формула вежливости при обращении**). Рад видеть вас, уважаемый Иван Степанович!

Значит, использовать это слово можно **только при обращении**? Может быть, в других случаях оно приобретает сниженное значение (ироничное, например)?  А если без имени, то и вовсе  негативное: не уважительное, а фамильярное, с оттенком неприязни, например: **Отойдите в сторонку, уважаемый, и уберите  сумку с дороги!**

Comment: "Может быть, в других случаях оно приобретает сниженное значение (ироничное, например)?А если без имени, то и вовсе негативное: не уважительное, а фамильярное, например..." - Что-то Ваш вопрос больше похож на ответ с примерами.

Comment: Не похож.  Мне до сих пор непонятно, КАК И КОГДА  такое хорошее слово приобрело не слишком хорошую репутацию, обозначенную даже в словаре. И примеры тоже взяты из словаря.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мое субъективное мнение (а существует ли несубъективное по этому ворпросу?).
Обращение "уважаемый" без добавления имени, титула и т.п. воспринимается мной как легкое отклонение от нормы, характерное для речи некоторых персонажей, для которых русский - не родной. Именно как отклонение от нормы, перейдя в разговорный язык, оно приобрело оттенок насмешки, фамильярности и т.п.

Comment: О слове "уважаемый" без имени интересный материал http://newforum.gramota.ru/viewtopic.php?p=222787. Правильно ли обращается к нам гаишник? И еще вопрос: можно ли говорить "уважаемый Иван Степанович", если мы к нему не обращаемся. Есть ли здесь какой-нибудь подтекст, в  каких случаях так говорят?

Comment: (1) Этим стоит дополнить Ваш вопрос (2)По моим ощущениям, "уважаемый Иван Степанович", сказанное, даже  если мы к нему не обращаемся, в его присутствии, является как бы косвенным обращением, а сказанное в его в отсутствие - является таким же легким отклонением от нормы, как просто "уважаемый", но чаще с положительной коннотацией .

Comment: Вот пример: "Как говорил уважаемый Полиграф Полиграфович Шариков, слон - животное полезное".  (Тэк-с. Что вы скажете относительно слонов, дорогой Шариков? – недоверчиво спросил Филипп Филиппович у Шарикова. Тот обиделся. – Что ж, я не понимаю, что ли? Кот – другое дело, а слоны – животные полезные, – ответил Шариков).  Здесь есть дополнительная коннотация?

Comment: Мне  тут пришла в голову мысль о том, что ОТРИЦАТЕЛЬНАЯ КОННОТАЦИЯ  в сочетании " как говорит уважаемый Иван Иванович" имеет место тогда, когда нет особых причин выделять Ивана Ивановича среди других или даже этот Иван Иванович, напротив, никакого уважения не заслуживает.  Так что иронический подтекст в таких случаях отнюдь не редкость.

Answer (score 2):

**уважаемый**

**2**. ...*в знач.сущ.*  **уважаемый**, **уважаемая**. *Устар., теперь ирон*.
 В обращении как выражение фамильярности или пренебрежения.
  - *Уважаемый, не верьте! - зашептал он, прикладывая руку к сердцу.* Чехов, Палата N6.
  *Уважаемая ...Надо быть мягче, надо быть добрее...все мы - люди.* М.Горький, Дачники.
 Словарь русского языка в четырех томах, том IV, **1961**

Если *тогда*  **уважаемый** уже было "устаревшим, теперь ироничным", то *сейчас* и подавно.
Это, конечно, мое личное, субъективное мнение. Но ведь Чехов и Горький - "носители" языка. Поэтому думаю, что с таким фамильярно-пренебрежительным оттенком употребляется и в наше время, причем всеми.
(Первый том словаря датирован 1957 годом.)

Answer (score 2):

Формулировка - да, оставляет желать... Но как есть.

> Значит, использовать это слово можно только при обращении?

Нет, конечно, не только.

> Эту ахинею утвердил и подписал уважаемый человек, префект Центрального округа Музыкантский, а сподвигло его на этот шаг, судя по
>   всему, техническое заключение [Ирина Александрова. Жизнь на
>   стройплощадке (1999) // «Адвокат», 1999.01.18] [омонимия снята] ←…→
>
> Родился он, это точно, в русской семье, но кто-то был рядом, с иной фонетикой, человек в семье уважаемый, не с решающим голосом, но и
>   не с совещательным, авторитетный был человек, из чужих краёв, прибалт
>   или чухонец. [Анатолий Азольский. Лопушок // «Новый Мир», 1998]
>   [омонимия снята] ←…→

(нацкорпус)

И много еще примеров.
Причем, если в первом случае еще можно найти какое-то ехидство (а его бы и не было, будь слово "уважаемый" ироничным), то второй уж никак нельзя осмыслить негативно.

> Может быть, в других случаях оно приобретает сниженное значение
>   (ироничное, например)?

Может, конечно, и приобретать, но совершенно не обязательно. См. выше.

> А если без имени, то и вовсе негативное: не уважительное, а
>   фамильярное, с оттенком неприязни, например: Отойдите в сторонку,
>   уважаемый, и уберите сумку с дороги!

А вот это вопрос интересный. Скорее как раз наоборот...

Само обращение подобного типа до 1917-го в русском языке использовалось при сниженной речи (наряду, например, с "господин хороший"), в письменной, тем более - официальной, речи вряд ли использовалось, ни с именем, ни самостоятельно.

Навскидку - оно единично встречалось в переписке в первые годы советской власти взамен упраздненного "милостивый государь" пока не было окончательно вытеснено "товарищем". В быту же не то чтобы исчезло, но использовалось довольно вяло, без какого-то иронического оттенка. Но, как верно подмечено, утратив связь с именем-фамилией стало звучать несколько комично. Ну что за уважение, если не знаешь имени того, к кому обращаешься?! Русский менталитет этого принимает. Так появилось это иронично-ехидное "уважаемый" без имени собственного. Но нельзя сказать, что его часто употребляли при советской власти...

По моим (и не только) наблюдениям в последние годы оно, однако, активизировалось - и при этом постепенно теряет однозначно ироническое наполнение.

Слышал версию, что всему виной массовый приток (в столицы особенно) носителей восточного менталитета. В Средней Азии, на Кавказе - да и вообще на Востоке - подобное обращение к незнакомому, особенно старшему, - в порядке вещей и вполне уважительно. Мне, как человеку немного знакомому с восточными традициями, такое объяснение хорошо понятно, но я его не очень  разделяю, ибо при всей логичности оно несколько притянуто за уши. Не так у нас и много "гостей с Востока", а отношение к ним не такое, чтобы эти манеры массово перенимать.

> Отойдите в сторонку, уважаемый, и уберите сумку с дороги!

А вот это - как раз пример нового использования, о котором я говорил в предыдущем абзаце. Нельзя сказать, что здесь какая-то а) фамильярность, б) пренебрежительность. Все зависит от сопутствующих тона, интонации... жестикуляции даже.

Вся беда, видимо, в том, что товарищами мы быть перестали, а господами вряд ли уже станем: была надежда до начала 2000-х, но история пошла другим путем. Ну, может, хоть уважаемыми останемся.

Answer (score 1):

> > Значит, использовать это слово можно только при обращении?

— В порядке старшинства, господа, — сказал Остап, — начнем с *уважаемого Максима Петровича*.

> > А если без имени, то и вовсе негативное: не уважительное, а фамильярное, с оттенком неприязни

Ну да, примерно как *милостивый государь*. Или *любезнейший* при обращении к любям низкого звания. Ничего удивительного.

Answer (score 0):

Уважаемый - оценочное прилагательное, а любое оценочное слово мы можем употребить в прямом и переносном значении.

В официальной речи (делопроизводстве и выступлениях с трибуны, официальных поздравлениях) "уважаемый" - вежливая форма обращения: обращения должны соответствовать обычаям официального этикета, которые предусматривают сложное обращение к адресату, состоящее из имени собственного (имени и отчества) и прилагательного, наиболее соответствующего случаю обращения, например:
"Уважаемый Матвей Сергеевич!";
"Уважаемая Антонина Петровна!";.

При обращении к нескольким адресатам допустимо обращение:
"Уважаемые коллеги!";
"Уважаемые господа!";
"Глубокоуважаемые депутаты!".

При отсутствии сведений об имени и отчестве адресата или по другим причинам используются следующие формулировки обращения:
"Уважаемый гражданин Хохлов!";
"Уважаемая госпожа Михайлова!".

Вот как Вы относитесь к праздничным поздравлениям ветеранов и заслуженных людей от Путина лично? Уважаемый_________________(вписывается имя)... и факсимильная подпись Путина. Мой престарелый свёкор просто счастлив, что его поздравил Путин, а сосед молча складывает в стопку, понимая, что Путин  о нём  даже не знает, что это для проформы, чтобы показать, что в стране о них помнят.Это официальная бумага и только, но ведь и то хорошо, что там, наверху, помнят не лично о нём(хотя имя есть), а о заслугах ветеранов вообще. Это тоже один из случаев официального этикета.

В личной переписке или бытовом разговоре это слово иногда является выразительным средством, например, входит в оксюморон или каламбур:"Но наш неуважаемый уважаемый Иван Иваныч так часто обманывал наши ожидания...", "Неуважаемый уважаемый шеф проворовался".

А вот обезличенное "уважаемый" -  субстантивированное прилагательное, употребляемое в разговорной речи,может употребляться в двух случаях - как вежливая форма обращения к незнакомому человеку(один из способов начать общение, когда ты показываешь свою уважительность к людям вообще, любая личность должна быть уважаема) или как ирония, сомнение в уважаемости:
" Ну, нельзя же так себя вести, уважаемый!"(как бы призыв быть уважаемым)."Эй ты, уважаемый, что творишь?" - явная ирония и эвфемизм одновременно:и неуважение показал, и негодяем не назвал, тоже вежливость.

Пример использования: [Уважаемый - неуважаемый. Василий Тресков | proza.ru](http://proza.ru/2014/04/26/1767)